# How do I find all reports in SSRS where a field is mentioned in the SQL

Tags: ssrs-2008-r2, reportserver

How do I find the column/field **EpiHRG** where it is referenced in the SQL code of an SSRS report other than manually going through 100's.

Answer (score 1):

You could try opening all of your ssrs queries in SSMS and then doing a ctrl+f search. It will search all current tabs and just make a note of which queries have an occurrence and which dataset and report they belong to.